A beautiful property of two parabolas that intersect in four points
I have just come up with a very cool property of two parabolas intersecting at four points, I want to know whether this property is already known or not and how to prove it.

We have two parabolas that intersect at four points, we draw the tangents to these two parabolas at those four points and determine the intersection points of the tangents on the same parabola.   We will get two perfect quadrilaterals, each of which is supposed to have 3 diagonals, but the beauty of it is that they both have those same 3 diagonals.   Furthermore, these three diagonals intersect at three points.   If we draw the circle that passes through these three points, its center will be the point of intersection of the indices of these two parabolas.
Please mention any references to the property if known previously.
I think it is a very beautiful feature, and the most beautiful thing is that the basis was not a geometric drawing on geogebra, but a geometric drawing on paper and a guess that groups of four points would fall on one line and this was correct

But after putting the drawing on Geogebra, I was able to get the result further afield, where I discovered a third line of this kind, and I discovered the property related to the center of that circle.

There may be a way to generalize this to arbitrary conics. (There seems to be a version for ellipses, at least...)

Yes, I noticed that the property of lines passing through 4 points is true for all conic sections, but the property of the center of the circle passing through the intersections of those lines is only true for parabolas. @Semiclassical

Very interesting, once more. Just a point of vocabulary : the circle's center is the point of intersection of the "directrices" (instead of "indices") of the parabolas.

Nice result - it can be proven as follows:
By pascal’s theorem (applied several times), we find that the blue lines in your picture are actually colinear. Then the problem follows from the following:
Lemma 1. Let $ABCD$ be points on a parabola whose diagonals make a triangle $PQR$. Then the circumcenter of $PQR$ lies on the directrix of the parabola.
To prove this, let the tangents to the parabola at $ABCD$ form a quadrilateral $XYZW$. Then by Theorem 1.11 in https://geometry.ru/books/conic_e.pdf, we see that the Gauss-Bodenmiller line (the line through the four orthocenters of triangles formed by the lines of the quad) is in fast the directrix of the parabola. So the result follows from:
Lemma 2. Let $XYZW$ be a quadrilateral whose diagonals intersect in $UVR$. Lines $XZ$ and $YW$ cut $UV$ at $P$ and $Q$. Then the circumcenter of $PQR$ lies on the Gauss-Bodenmiller line of $XYWZ$.
Let $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ be the circles with diameter $XZ$ and $YW$. Then from harmonic bundles in quadrilaterals, we find $(X,Z;R,P)$ is harmonic, and thus $R$ and $P$ swap under inversion in $\Omega_1$. In particular, $(PQR)$ is orthogonal to $\Omega_1$. Similarly, we find $(PQR)$ orthogonal to $\Omega_2$. Hence the center of $(PQR)$ has same power to both these circles, and thus lies on their radical axis - i.e. the Gauss-Bodenmiller line of $XYZW$.
